# Using package "pcalg" in R, and getting error: "error in pMax[i,j] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm very, very new to R and am learning for a summer research position. I have a question regarding the correct syntax of the function "pc" in the package "pcalg." I have generated a random DAG using "randomDAG" and I used this code:

```
R> myDAG<-randomDAG(5, .5)
R> V<-"V1"
R> estEQC<-pc(myDAG, indeptest=gaussCItest, alpha=.01,labels=V, verbose=TRUE)
R> estEQC
```

And it gives me the message: `Error in pMax[i, j] : subscript out of bounds`

It must be the syntax that's wrong, right? Or maybe I have a misunderstanding of what these arguments need to be.

Comment: The pc algorithm is for learning a graph structure from raw data, you have passed it a graph. (worth a read [pdf download](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijv8PUovHNAhXFCMAKHZKdCYoQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2Fafs%2Fcs.cmu.edu%2Fproject%2Flearn-43%2Flib%2Fphotoz%2F.g%2Fscottd%2Ffullbook.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGITKctuTPIsh1s4EuVZf0dg2Mw-w))

Comment: I'm having trouble with the arguments of the function then. Could you explain suffStat, indepTest, and alpha for me as they are the main arguments? I'm not sure I understand them.

Comment: So the pc algorithm is for learning the equivalence graph of a dag, from data:   so you need to pass it some data. The `pc` help pages don't give
much info on how to pass the arguments, although the examples are fairly intuitive. As you are using `gaussCItest` (the test to see if nodes are independent), look at the help pages `?gaussCItest` to see the arguments that `suffstat` takes: `C` the correlation matrix of the data, and `n` the number of observations. `alpha` gives the sig. level of the conditional tests.

Comment: Example (similar to example 1 from `?pc`): `dat <- iris[1:4] ;
pc.fit <- pc(suffStat = list(C = cor(dat), n = nrow(dat)), indepTest = gaussCItest, alpha=0.05, labels = colnames(dat), verbose = TRUE);
plot(pc.fit)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used your model and it worked for me, but when I used a matrix of my own, it gave me this message: "In sqrt(n - length(S) - 3) : NaNs produced" 28 times. When it does work, it gives me a graph with no edges at all. What is the issue?

Comment: for your first Q, I cant say without seeing the data. For Q2, it is quite possible to get a graph with no edges if all of the variables are conditionally independent from each other (at your specified significance level alpha) . Did you look at the values in the correlation matrix before passing it to  `pc`? This could actually be an issue to one as well, as `cor` may have to have further arguments passed to it if your data has missing. etc